# Why are the analytical graphs not popping up with my code?

Tags: sas

I am trying to analyze my survey data, but the SAS software cant seem to run the graphs I am looking for.

What have I done wrong?

```
ODS HTML CLOSING;

ODS LISTING;

OPTIONS NODATE NONUMBER LS=78 PS=50;

DATA A;

INPUT X1    X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30;

CARDS;

2,3,3,3,2,3,4,4,3,3,2,3,2,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,5,5,5,4,4,5,3,4,4,4

2,2,3,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,3,2,4,4,5,4,4,2,2,5,5,5,4,4,5,3,4,4,4

2, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,

PROC PRINCOMP DATA=A OUT=OUT2;

VAR X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30;

RUN;

PROC PRINTDATA=OUT2;

RUN;

PROC CORR DATA=OUT2;

VAR X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30;

WITH PRIN1 PRIN2;

RUN;

proc plot data=out2;

plot prin2*prin1

run;
```

Thank you.

Comment: in cards values are separated by space not number. Also there are 29 values per line but 30 input vars

Comment: @Lee would should i do if those valued have to be separated in commas? What should be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nominally, the default value separator for `INPUT` is a space.

When `CARDS` data is comma separated the DATA Step will need an `INFILE` statement that specifies how to parse (along with the input statement) the input line.

You should also learn how to use variables lists, such as `VAR1-VAR30`.

```
DATA WANT;

  INFILE CARDS 
    DELIMITER=','    /* values are separated by comma */
    MISSOVER         /* if not enough values in the input line the remaining variables are assigned missing */
  ;

  INPUT X1-X30;  /* grab value for 30 variables */
CARDS;
2,3,3,3,2,3,4,4,3,3,2,3,2,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,5,5,5,4,4,5,3,4,4,4
2,2,3,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,3,2,4,4,5,4,4,2,2,5,5,5,4,4,5,3,4,4,4
2, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
run;
```